# Resize Clipping Path on window resize in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, resize, clipping

I was wondering how to resize a Clipping path dynamically when resizing the window. Right now I'm taking a rectangle in Expression Blend that resizes with the window. Applying this rectangle to a circle as a clipping path makes the rectangle fixed, and it won't resize anymore.

I've seen different ways of making clipping paths in XAML, in the Clip="" property as well as  style markup. But I haven't succeeded yet in finding a proper XAML solution.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for an answer to the the same question (that's how I found your post) and I came across this:

http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2008/10/03/wpf-easy-rounded-corners-for-anything/

Not sure it will work for you if you have a more complex shape that you would like to use as the clipping path, but if you are just looking to round some corners that will scale automatically, I suggest you check it out. It uses a VisualBrush bound to a border element instead of a clipping path. So far I have found it to be a pretty elegant solution for my needs.